# Seam 3 - Security Module - Identity Management with JPAIdendityStore

Tags: java, identity, seam3

I'm using seam 3 security module with identity management with JpaIdentityStore, postgres and Jboss 6 to create users on my database, but it's not working. I'm following the example provided (http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/security/latest/reference/en-US/html/security-identitymanagement.html).

I just wrote this simple code to create an user:

```
 @Model
    public class MemberRegistration {

    @Inject 
    Identity identity;

    @Inject 
    IdentitySession identitySession;


    public void register() throws Exception {       

        PersistenceManager pm = identitySession.getPersistenceManager();
        pm.createUser("testuser");

    }
}
```

with this JSF fragment:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{bundle.defaultHeader_createAccount}" action="#{memberRegistration.register}"/>
```

.. and get this is the exception:

```
13:03:17,765 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.external.dialogues.DialogueFilter.doFilter(DialogueFilter.java:48) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:72) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1171) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1096) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.picketlink.idm.impl.repository.WrapperIdentityStoreRepository.createIdentityObject(WrapperIdentityStoreRepository.java:144) [:1.5.0.Alpha02]
    at org.picketlink.idm.impl.api.session.managers.PersistenceManagerImpl.createUser(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:132) [:1.5.0.Alpha02]
    at com.manzana.bommenu.controller.MemberRegistration.register(MemberRegistration.java:27) [:]
    at com.manzana.bommenu.controller.org$jboss$weld$bean-jboss$classloader:id="vfs:$$$home$fzaffari$workspace$3manzana$$metadata$$plugins$org$jboss$ide$eclipse$as$core$JBoss_6$0_Runtime_Server1302099615051$deploy$bommenu$war"-ManagedBean-class_com$manzana$bommenu$controller$MemberRegistration_$$_WeldClientProxy.register(org$jboss$weld$bean-jboss$classloader:id="vfs:$$$home$fzaffari$workspace$3manzana$$metadata$$plugins$org$jboss$ide$eclipse$as$core$JBoss_6$0_Runtime_Server1302099615051$deploy$bommenu$war"-ManagedBean-class_com$manzana$bommenu$controller$MemberRegistration_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:196) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.lookupIdentityType(JpaIdentityStore.java:1108) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1140) [:3.0.0.Final]
    ... 56 more

13:03:17,781 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] #{memberRegistration.register}: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object: javax.faces.FacesException: #{memberRegistration.register}: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:324) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:67) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.external.dialogues.DialogueFilter.doFilter(DialogueFilter.java:48) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:72) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:274) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [:6.0.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:181) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.event(CatalinaContext.java:285) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.catalina.CatalinaContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(CatalinaContext.java:261) [:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:88) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:100) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.request.ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.invoke(ActiveRequestResponseCacheValve.java:53) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:362) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_24]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 38 more
Caused by: org.picketlink.idm.common.exception.IdentityException: Error creating identity object
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1171) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1096) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.picketlink.idm.impl.repository.WrapperIdentityStoreRepository.createIdentityObject(WrapperIdentityStoreRepository.java:144) [:1.5.0.Alpha02]
    at org.picketlink.idm.impl.api.session.managers.PersistenceManagerImpl.createUser(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:132) [:1.5.0.Alpha02]
    at com.manzana.bommenu.controller.MemberRegistration.register(MemberRegistration.java:27) [:]
    at com.manzana.bommenu.controller.org$jboss$weld$bean-jboss$classloader:id="vfs:$$$home$fzaffari$workspace$3manzana$$metadata$$plugins$org$jboss$ide$eclipse$as$core$JBoss_6$0_Runtime_Server1302099615051$deploy$bommenu$war"-ManagedBean-class_com$manzana$bommenu$controller$MemberRegistration_$$_WeldClientProxy.register(org$jboss$weld$bean-jboss$classloader:id="vfs:$$$home$fzaffari$workspace$3manzana$$metadata$$plugins$org$jboss$ide$eclipse$as$core$JBoss_6$0_Runtime_Server1302099615051$deploy$bommenu$war"-ManagedBean-class_com$manzana$bommenu$controller$MemberRegistration_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_24]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_24]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_24]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:196) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:43) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:56) [:6.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102) [:2.0.3-]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84) [:2.0.3-]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.lookupIdentityType(JpaIdentityStore.java:1108) [:3.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink.JpaIdentityStore.createIdentityObject(JpaIdentityStore.java:1140) [:3.0.0.Final]
    ... 56 more
```

Debugging the seam's source file, i've noticed that in this method bellow, on JpaIdentityStore class, the EntityManager em is null and this is what throws the first exception.

```
 protected Object lookupIdentityType(String identityType, EntityManager em)
   {      
      try
      {
         Property<Object> typeNameProp = modelProperties.get(PROPERTY_IDENTITY_TYPE_NAME);

         // If there is no identity type table, just return the name
         if (typeNameProp == null) return identityType;

         Object val = em.createQuery(
               "select t from " + typeNameProp.getDeclaringClass().getName() + 
               " t where t." + typeNameProp.getName() +
                " = :identityType")
               .setParameter("identityType", identityType)
               .getSingleResult();
         return val;
      }
      catch (NoResultException ex)
      {
         return null;
      }      
   }
```

My config files:

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="bommenuDatabase" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/bommenuDatasource</jta-data-source>

        <properties>

             <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
             <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>            
             <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
             <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

seam-beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:s="urn:java:ee" 
   xmlns:security="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.security"
   xmlns:plidm="urn:java:org.jboss.seam.security.management.picketlink"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://jboss.org/schema/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd">     

   <interceptors>
      <class>org.jboss.seam.transaction.TransactionInterceptor</class>
   </interceptors>


     <plidm:JpaIdentityStoreConfiguration>
      <s:replaces/>
      <plidm:identityClass>com.manzana.bommenu.domain.IdentityObject</plidm:identityClass>
      <plidm:credentialClass>com.manzana.bommenu.domain.IdentityObjectCredential</plidm:credentialClass>
      <plidm:relationshipClass>com.manzana.bommenu.domain.IdentityObjectRelationship</plidm:relationshipClass>
      <plidm:roleTypeClass>com.manzana.bommenu.domain.IdentityRoleName</plidm:roleTypeClass>
      <plidm:attributeClass>com.manzana.bommenu.domain.IdentityObjectAttribute</plidm:attributeClass>
   </plidm:JpaIdentityStoreConfiguration>

</beans>
```

I aprecciate any suggestion beacuse a really don't know what do.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Configuration of Seam Persistence is much easier since 3.1.0.Beta3. Please look at the documentation and other examples for the correct annotations (the annotation route is now preferred over Seam Config).